# How to add a line plot plot for the average value across multiple groups using groupby in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the code (below) that members of stack overflow have helped me put together to take a csv like and use a for loop for multiple lines (grouped by a certain value in one of the columns).

[image: Example Data Table]

I'm trying to plot the mean across each of those grouped values and their plots. I'm realizing im confused on how to actually create a mean across multiple columns for each group. Help on this and how to adjust the code would be more than appreciated!

The desired outcome is here [image: The desired outcome figure.]

the code I have is here

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

#read CSV
df=pd.read_csv('/Users/fabienlaugier/Documents/GeoComp/Data/Profiles.csv')

#Make Variables from dataframe columns
Value = df['Value']
Xposition = df['Xposition']
SectionName = df['Profile']

#Set up figure that will plot multiple line plots over each Group
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for Profile, group in df.groupby('SectionName'):
    group.plot(x='Xposition', y='Value', ax=ax, label=Profile, c='grey')
ax.set_title('SectionName')
ax.set_xlabel("Xposition")
ax.set_ylabel("Value")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach with `pivot`:

```
s = df.pivot('Xposition', 'SectionName','Value')
# in case of duplicated data:
# s = df.pivot_table(index='Xposition', columns='SectionName', values='Value', aggfunc='mean')

ax = s.plot(color='gray')
s.mean(1).plot(ax=ax, color='b', linestyle='--', label='Mean')
ax.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

**Note**: if you remove `color='gray'` in `s.plot`, you get:

[image]

Comment: I tried your code to the sample data and it works great, however when I tried this on raw data file that I have I get the following error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape." 

This is obviously happening on the pivot command, but I can't see how the raw data I have is really much different from the test data. I know I have duplicates in the rows in the pivot, but isn't that the point? that I have multiple lines (groups) that will have the same values for the x-axis? 

Is there a way to get around this - or am I completely missing something.  Thanks!!

Comment: That means your data have duplicated values, e.g. two rows with `Xposition==1` and `SectionName==A`. In which case, you may want to merge them into one row, e.g. with `mean()` or `sum()`. See update.